# Openshift Tomcat Mysql Javascript Connection String

Tags: java, mysql, string, tomcat, openshift

This is part of the jsp for the registration into a website, it takes the data inserted by the user in another html and put them in a mysql db... Everything was working fine in local, but when I uploaded the website to Openshift, it gave an error for the String matot and cittatot : **The method join(String, String[]) is undefined for the type String**

I am also not so sure that the connection string is right lol

Someone could gently help me?

```html
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>

<%

  
  
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
 String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
 String[] citta = request.getParameterValues("citta");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
 String titolo = request.getParameter("titolo");
 String numero = request.getParameter("numero");
 String prezzo = request.getParameter("prezzo");
 String info = request.getParameter("info");
 String[] materia = request.getParameterValues("materia");
    
String matot = String.join(",",materia);
 String cittatot = String.join(",",citta);
 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    String host = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");
String port = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
String username = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
String password = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");

String url = String.format(":mysql://%s:%s/easylesson", host, port);
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    //ResultSet rs;
   
    int var = st.executeUpdate(" insert into iscritti(email,pass,datareg,titolo,numero,prezzo,info,cittatot,matot,name,surname) values ('" + email + "','" + pass + "', CURDATE(),'" + titolo + "','" +  numero+ "','" +  prezzo+ "','" +  info+ "','" +  cittatot+ "','" + matot + "','" + name + "','" +  surname+ "')");
```

Comment: Java 8 supports the static method String.join, but previous versions of Java don't.  Openshift must be using a version older than 8...  By the way, your connection string should look something like this: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema".

Comment: I solved the join problem using the StringUtils.join method. But there is still a error in the connection String... The one that you have write is just for local database I think. I'm using phpmy Admin cartridge, the database is on the openshift server

Comment: Edit:solved also the connection problem!

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat on OpenShift includes a pre-defined data source that you can use for this situation.  Try reading through the example information here: https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-ds.html about how to use it.